# Testing script won't

Tags: go

I'm a bit confused why Go test won't work properly.

```
├── datasource
│   ├── cache.go
│   ├── database.go
│   ├── datasource.go
│   └── datasource_test.go
├── main.go
└── README.md
```

This is my file directory structure.

I have inside datasource_test.go implemented this https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

i.e.,

```
package datasource

import "testing"

func TestAbs(t *testing.T) {
    got := Abs(-1)
    if got != 1 {
        t.Errorf("Abs(-1) = %d; want 1", got)
    }
}
```

my main directory is like this,

```
package main

import "datasource/datasource.go"

func main() {
    // 
        }()
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I assume it's due to not import.

Comment: Go is not PHP and is not JavaScript: in Go, you impot _packages,_ not files. While package import paths may indeed correlate with filesystem pathnames, this is not what you should be thinking of. Can you please start with reading basic material on organizing Go code? I suggest starting right [here](https://golang.org/doc/) and reading top to bottom.

Comment: A note on terminology: There are no "scripts" in Go. Go is compiled. By definition, scripts are interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `go test ./...` to test all packages. The way you import the packages is wrong as well as you don't need to import the packages for testing purposes. `go test` command will help you run your tests.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, just trying to wrap my head around the language!

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html is waiting for you to start out.

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect @halil